# What adjective describes incorrect assumptions?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I wanted to  apologise for making incorrect assumptions in some correspondence and wrote "I apologise for my presumptive wording".  Then I looked up  "presumptive" and see it means:

> Providing a reasonable basis for belief or acceptance

Not at all what I was trying to say.  What adjective should I have used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Presumptuous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/presumptuous)

Comment: I suppose it *is* the right word in contrast to OP's *presumptive*", but *presumtuous* is a pretty "loaded" term, which I think is well-defined as *going beyond what is right or proper; excessively forward.* Personally, I'd feel more comfortable apologising for simply having *made incorrect assumptions*.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the word, funny how its pretty much unrelated to "presumptive".  But I think in future I'll go with a direct apology for the assumption because I _assumed_ rather than _presumed_.

Answer (score 2):

You're making this too hard. If you want to apologize for your incorrect assumptions, just say, "I apologize for my incorrect assumptions." If you want to avoid saying you were wrong, you can say, "I apologize for my hasty assumptions."