# What is a single word/phrase that can be used in place of 'mistaken assumption' or 'incorrect belief'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, synonyms

What is a suitable word that can be used in the below story scenario?

I've considered the following words; Delusion, Conjecture, Fallacy, Belief, Erroneous assumption. Is there a better word anyone can suggest?

---

In a small village there was a girl afflicted with a mortal disease. The medicine to which was expensive and could only be obtained from a doctor who lived seven days journey away.

Her family had the money, but no one to make the perilous journey.

A man, her lover volunteered, and promised to return with the medicine. He got the medicine, but on the way back was mauled by a bear and succumbed to his injuries.

His absence caused the village folk to gossip that he had taken the money and ran away.

The girl's condition worsened, and at soon she passed away under the (**mistaken assumption/incorrect belief**) that the man had tricked her and ran off.

Comment: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241904/expression-for-wrong-common-knowledge-a-set-of-common-misconceptions)

[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297877/what-is-another-word-for-a-false-belief-or-opinion-on-something-that-people-hold/297879#297879)

[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49607/what-adjective-describes-incorrect-assumptions) --- they should answer your question.

Comment: She died under the misbelief that the man had tricked her and ran off.

Comment: What's wrong with each of the words that you've considered and rejected? Why have you rejected them? There are many words that could be used—including the ones you've listed. What are your criteria for picking the best one?

Comment: The more-or-less standard form is *The girl's condition worsened, and soon she **died believing/convinced** that the man had tricked her and run off.*

Comment: A misconception or presumption is probably the closest fit. Misunderstanding might also work.

Comment: @JasonBassford: The criteria is mostly something that 'sounds' or 'feels' right. Like Mark Twain said, the difference between lightning bug and lightning.